# Inspecting SQLlite DB while debugging

Tags: laravel, phpunit, xdebug

I'm doing some TDD while developing my Laravel app and would like to know if there is a way of inspecting the contents of a file-based SQLite DB while debugging with Xdebug.

I installed sqlitebrower which gives me access to the DB but if I reach a breakpoint in my code, the tables are empty - with the exception of (oddly) the migrations table.

Is there a way to view the DB while testing with Xdebug?

Comment: Just a wild guess (since I do not work with SQLite a lot): it could be that the DB is locked and other connection cannot see the changes while PHP process has some "exclusive" lock? In any case: PhpStorm has Databases panel (if you have that plugin enabled, which is by default) and it does support SQLite databases.

Comment: I use VSCode and it also has a plugin to view SQLite DBs which I found after writing this question, but it's the same situation - all tables empty apart from migrations.